# How to change woocommerce default theme - hello elementor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to stack 2 products on one product page in woocommerce. I have got template with product on the left side. Right side product I'm adding with shortcode 'product_id = x' (filled from custom fields) and it got different template, i think it's woocommerce default template. How can I change it? I'm using hello elementor and it doesn't have woocommerce folder in wp-content/hello-elementor.

Comment: Woocommerce normally uses the wordpress theme as it's base. but you're able to change a lot within that base by editing for example the products page template.

Comment: When i edit products page template - it edits left side. When i add hook - product_id it tooks template from i don't know where, that's the problem.